# How can I find the user who deleted a document from Google Drive after it's already been restored Google Vault

Tags: google-workspace

**Google Drive / Google Vault - Google Business Account.**

I have a document that was deleted maliciously and then restored by a manager. 
I was tasked with finding information on who deleted the document ***AFTER*** it had already been restored. I've looked through the documents history but there is only information about edits made to the doc. Would this show the user who deleted it? If not how would I excise the information (would it be via vault or inside drive?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Admin Console](https://admin.google.com) > Reporting > Audit & Investigation > Drive log events > Add filter: "Document ID"